# Jmeter - How to escape % as special character in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a script where in my request I use as:

```
"requirements": [
    {
      "key": "SITEID",
      "operand": "%",
      "value": "1,202,209"
    }
  ]
```

I got exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - Error at index 0 in: "","
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:232) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:142) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.visualizers.RequestViewHTTP.decodeQuery(RequestViewHTTP.java:336) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.visualizers.RequestViewHTTP.getQueryMap(RequestViewHTTP.java:290) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.visualizers.RequestViewHTTP.setSamplerResult(RequestViewHTTP.java:216) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RequestPanel.setSamplerResult(RequestPanel.java:116) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SamplerResultTab.setupTabPane(SamplerResultTab.java:238) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.valueChanged(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:385) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.valueChanged(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:363) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2967) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3456) ~[?:?]
```

What should be done in order to escape the % sign?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using "Parameters" section - tick "URL Encode" box

   [image]
2. If you're adding the JSON to URL directly - wrap it into [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) like:

   ```
   ${__urlencode({"requirements":[{"key":"SITEID"\,"operand":"%"\,"value":"1\,202\,209"}]})}
   ```
3. Make sure that you **really** need to use [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) method as the request body looks more like to be a [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) one
4. You may also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema)

Comment: I am using: Post request + body data. sry, I wasn't clear enough. 4 Content-type is sent as well

Comment: Is there any way to use 'URL Encode' when using body data without wrapping & reformating the whole JSON?